# Angular router always redirecting to the same module

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

This is driving me crazy.
I have 3 simple routes in my app module:

```
routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/customers', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'customers', loadChildren: './components/customer#CustomerModule' },
    { path: 'promotions', loadChildren: './components/promotion#PromotionModule'}
];
```

In my customer module I have defined theses routes:

```
routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: CustomerComponent, children: [
            { path: '', component: CustomerSearchComponent },
            { path: ':id', component: CustomerDetailComponent }
    ]}
];
```

And in my promotion modules:

```
routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: PromotionComponent },
    { path: 'new', component: PromotionNewComponent }
];
```

I have a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in my AppComponent and CustomerComponent.
The thing is, when I am going to the route /promotions, I am still getting redirected to the CustomerModule -> CustomerComponent -> CustomerSearch

Why is this happening? I can't figure it out

**EDIT:**
For navigation I have a header Component which contains:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a [routerLink]="['./customers']"
                   routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
                    Customers
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a [routerLink]="['./promotions']"
                   routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
                    Promotions
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

The app component is like this:

```
<app-header></app-header>

<main class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

Comment: How are you navigating? Are you using `routerLink`? Or `.navigate`? What does that code look like?

Comment: @DeborahK I just edited my post. I am using routerLink, but even when I enter the url in the address bar, it's the same

Comment: Have you tried turning on route tracing to see if that provides any insight into what is going on?

Comment: Yes but that was not very helpful. The 'promotions' route is matched but in the tree it's like AppComponent -> CustomerComponent -> CustomerSearchComponent

Comment: Because you have a static link, why not omit the brackets like so:
`<a routerLink='/user/bob'>link to user component</a>`.

Maybe this will help?

Comment: Try taking the dot out: `[routerLink]="['/customers']"` Otherwise its attempting to do relative routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to specify your full routes, even in the feature module routing.

Whats happening is it's going into your Customer routing and finding the path '' + '' and landing on the CustomerSearchComponent.

Try changing the base path for the customer routing to be 'customer' instead of '' and changing the paths in your Promotion routing to 'promotion' and 'promotion/new'

Comment: It's working but I dont' why my code isn't. According to the documentation, the routes are adding up. If I have 'promotion' in my parent component I shouldn't have to repeat it in the child component

Comment: It confused me at first too, it seems like it would be better if it worked that way. I think the routes only add up when they are nested within each other like in your Admin routing object with the children array. It doesnt seem to nest/add up when its going from one Module(ie the AppModule) and a different module(ie. your PromotionModule)